# AWS lambda layer for packages mne and pyedflib

Tags: amazon-web-services, numpy, aws-lambda-layers

I am having a problem making a AWS layer for mne and pyedflib packages using python3.7 and my numpy version is 1.21.6.
Created a python environment , activated the env and pip install mne pyedflib.
Then I too the site-packages and put them in a file like this: python\lib\python3.7\site-packages
then zipped it and uploaded it to AWS lambda layer

I am getting this error when I test my lambda :

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'src/handlers/mff_to_edf': \n\nIMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!\n\nImporting the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for\nmany reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was\ninstalled.\n\nWe have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:\n\n    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html\n\nPlease note and check the following:\n\n  * The Python version is: Python3.7 from \"/var/lang/bin/python3.7\"\n  * The NumPy version is: \"1.21.6\"\n\nand make sure that they are the versions you expect.\nPlease carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.\n\nOriginal error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'\n",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'src/handlers/mff_to_edf': 
IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.
We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
Please note and check the following:
* The Python version is: Python3.7 from "/var/lang/bin/python3.7"
* The NumPy version is: "1.21.6"
and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.
Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath
```

I tried uninstalling and installing numpy and also to take numpy from already exist layer.
I also tried locally and it works.